# How to extract a value coming from selenium driver.find_element_by_id

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I am trying to automate some test cases, for on test case I need a particular temperature value in integer. However, the value coming from

`driver.find_element_by_id("temperature").text`

is a string like 12°C. I want to extract 12 as an integer. See the screenshot for better understanding.[image]

Comment: `<your_code>.text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see when you do,

```
driver.find_element_by_id("temperature").text
```

it is gonna return a string.

so it will look like this **"12°C"**

see below, we will split using `'°'`, this and we will have an array, and we would be interesting in first element of that. Below is the full demonstration.

```
s = "12°C"
a = s.split('°')

print(type(s))
b = int(a[0])
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract number from a string with this:

```
import re

print (re.findall('\d+', str1 ))
```

Where str1 is a string you extracting from a web element